# How do I create a letter pyramid?

Tags: c, char

I'm trying to create a letter pyramid.

My code compiles, and it works initially, but it won't print after the initial prompt of asking the user to input a letter. Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
  intmain(void {
    char letter = 'A';
    char display;
    char output;
    int row;
    char spaces = ' ';

    printf ("Please enter a lowercase letter!");
    scanf ("%c", &letter);

    while ((letter < 96) || (letter > 122)) {
      printf ("That's not lowercase.");
      scanf ("%c", &letter);
    }

    else if ((letter > 96) || (letter < 122)) {
      while (1) {
        letter = letter - 32;
        printf ("%c", letter -1);
        printf ("\n\n");
        spaces = letter - 1;
        putchar = (spaces);
        letter++
        spaces++
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The end result should look like this. Say that the user entered `E`:

```
----------A
---------ABA
--------ABCBA
-------ABCDCBA
------ABCDEDCBA
```

So, the letter entered would be the center letter at the bottom of the pyramid.

Comment: Tags here have specific meaning. Please read the tag description before using it, and only use the ones that actually apply to your question. The *pyramid* tag is about a specific Python-based framework, and has no applicability to your question whatsoever, and I've removed it from your question. You should also post your actual code; what you've posted here won't compile at all (there are clear typos and syntax errors in it), which means there's no way it could "work initially" either.

Comment: http://ideone.com/O4ZoNl

Answer (score 1):

Just gave it a try and for me it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

char initialCharacter = 'A';
char characterToPrintTo = 'J';
int levels;

void printSpaces(int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<" ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    levels = characterToPrintTo - initialCharacter + 1;
    int numberOfCharacters = 2 * levels - 1;
    int maxChar, diff;
    for(int level = 1; level <= levels; level++)
    {
        maxChar = 2 * level - 1;
        if(maxChar < numberOfCharacters)
            diff = numberOfCharacters - maxChar;
        else diff = 0;
        printSpaces(diff/2);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxChar; i++)
        {
            if(i < maxChar / 2 + 1)
                std::cout<< (char) (initialCharacter + i);
            else
                std::cout<< (char) (initialCharacter + maxChar - i - 1);
        }
        printSpaces(diff/2);
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
         A
        ABA
       ABCBA
      ABCDCBA
     ABCDEDCBA
    ABCDEFEDCBA
   ABCDEFGFEDCBA
  ABCDEFGHGFEDCBA
 ABCDEFGHIHGFEDCBA
ABCDEFGHIJIHGFEDCBA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string letters{};

    std::cout << "Enter a string of letters to create a Letter Pyramid from it: ";
    getline(std::cin, letters);

    size_t num_letters = letters.length();

    int position {0};

    // for each letter in the string
    for (char c: letters) {

        size_t num_spaces = num_letters - position;
        while (num_spaces > 0) {
            std::cout << " ";
            --num_spaces;
        }

        // Display in order up to the current character
        for (size_t j=0; j < position; j++) {
            std::cout << letters.at(j);
        }

        // Display the current 'center' character
        std::cout << c;

        // Display the remaining characters in reverse order
        for (int j=position-1; j >=0; --j) {
            // You can use this line to get rid of the size_t vs int warning 
            auto k = static_cast<size_t>(j);
            std::cout << letters.at(k);
        }

        std::cout << std::endl; // Don't forget the end line
        ++position;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        int spaces=s.length()-i-1;
        for(;spaces>0;spaces--){
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            cout<<s.at(j);
        }
        for(int k=i-1;k>=0;k--){
            cout<<s.at(k);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This problem is pretty easy once you realize that letter are just numbers. You can add and subtract them just like any other number.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char letter = 0;
  cout << "Enter a letter between A and Z";
  cin >> letter;
  cout << endl;

  for (int i = 'A'; i <= letter; i++) {
    for (int j = 'A'; j < i; j++)
      cout << (char)j;
    while (j >= 'A') {
      cout << (char)j;
      j--;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged with [tag:C] and not [tag:C++]

Comment: the whitespace is missing, `j` is used when its out of scope, and wrong language